# Preg match few times in same file

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
<b>Text 1</b><br><i>Text 2</i>

Some text - very long and not interesting.

<b>Text 3</b><br><i>Text 4</i>
```

How could I take text 1, text 2, text 3 and text 4 in one go when using preg match function?

Comment: Can you expand on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Use a DOM parser to process HTML, not regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input = '<b>Text 1</b><br><i>Text 2</i>
          Some text - very long and not interesting.
          <b>Text 3</b><br><i>Text 4</i>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($input);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('//i | //b');

$output = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $output[] = $item->textContent;
}

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Text 1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'Text 2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'Text 3' (length=6)
  3 => string 'Text 4' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pattern = '<b>([^<]+)</b><br><i>([^<]+)</i>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Results are in $matches. And yes, use a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear why you don’t want to use neither `DOM`, nor `preg_match_all`, but with `preg_match` it would be like:

```
$s = 'YOUR INPUT';

$pos = 0;
$res = [];
while(preg_match('/<[bi]>(.*?)<\/[bi]>/m', $s, $vals, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, $pos))
{
  $pos = $vals[1][1];
  $res[] = $vals[1][0];
}

print_r($res);
```